# Update Query should be performed only if there is change in data else dont perform update in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle DB, I have 4 columns but before updating the columns I need to check If these is any new change in data then only I need to perform update else I dont need to perform  update, Please Suggest how can I do this in ORACLE.

Suggest some sample query

Comment: Use `merge` statement.

Comment: I have Table Name TB_PTR_DETAILS where I need to check if there is any change in data only then I need to merge. The columns I need to compare is ForcastDuration, ForecastEndDate, ActualStart and Autual End. please suggest how can I write query for this. Please suggest sample of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE Statement.
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

For update only:

-- No not-matched clause, update only.

```
MERGE INTO test1 a
  USING all_objects b
    ON (a.object_id = b.object_id and a.status <> b.status)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.status = b.status;
```

Comment: My Table Name: TB_PTR_DETAILS, MYColumns are ForcastDuration and ForcastEndDate. I need to check if either of these have a change then only I need to update. Please suggest some query to check these OR condition